# how to sort the ip address in ascending order using java please give the example in detail . Following are the ip address

Tags: java, collections

how to sort the ip address in ascending order using  java please give the example in detail . Following are the ip address

```
123.4.245.23,
104.244.253.29,     
1.198.3.93,
32.183.93.40,
104.30.244.2,
104.244.4.1
```

Comment: Did you try searching for it on google? Or did you try out something on your own? At least going through documentation of `Collections`?

Comment: Degine "ascending order"  Should we take into consideration the IP groups or just the first one??

Comment: we should take the ip groups not the first one. please share me if you know something.

Answer (score 0):

Represent the IP addresses using [`java.net.InetAddress`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html), and write a class implementing [`Comparator<InetAddress>`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)